# CKEDITOR - Disable in Line text editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

On CKEDITOR when I select a text, a small editor appears.

I Need to disable this inline editor.

[CKEDITOR http://devsal.madnezz.com.br/v2/img/ckeditor.png](http://devsal.madnezz.com.br/v2/img/ckeditor.png)

I have tried to change some stuff on `CKEDITOR.editorConfig` but, no success.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You using CKEditor 4? Did you enable inline editing?

Comment: Yes, CKEditor4. Well, in the config.js about editing i have this line:

`{ name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] }`. Is something here I must change?

Comment: See if adding [disableAutoInline: true](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-cfg-disableAutoInline) to the config makes a difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the following information on the configuration and it worked.

```
config.removePlugins = 'floatingspace,panelbutton,panel,floatpanel,floating-tools,contextmenu,richcombo';
```

Answer (score 1):

`config.removePlugins = 'floating-tools';` should be enough.